# What port are these wires for?

Tags: wiring, walls

[image]

There are six wires. Four are held into four corners in the cutout with screws, while two wires are loose.

Comment: Is this how it was found?  Do you have a multimeter?

Comment: Where on the planet are you?

Answer (score 1):

Wire that supports 3 telephone lines, but in a house with 2 or 1, by the look of it. Standard telephone color scheme for twisted pair wiring. Could be serving some other low-voltage function or could be abandoned, but that's what the wire is, so that's probably what it was used for.

Also the box says "WE" which stands for "Western Electric" which was the manufacturing arm of "Ma Bell" (the old AT&T, when "the phone company" meant them, and nobody else.)

Comment: you beat me to the punch .. I had some interruptions, made my answer and your answer had appeared along with mine aargh matey..

Answer (score 0):

Telephone Line ..
Line 1.. 
Then you have Line 2 and Line 3..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/68117)

Comment: @mmathis removed question mark..